# Finding TFS version from TFS collection Uri

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, tfs

I have TFS collection URI (like ip:port), Is there any programming way to find TFS semantic version number from TFS collection URI e.g. any method or property in ADO rest client libraries (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=azure-devops-dotnet) to get version?

All version numbers are listed here: https://github.com/FokkoVeegens/AzureDevOpsServerVersions?tab=readme-ov-file#2005
Not necessarily, specific versions If I can find, Is this tfs collection belong to TFS2015, TFS2013 etc. that's also fine.

Comment: Why do you need to programmatically determine the version? If it's to figure out what version of REST APIs are available, the easy solution is just to default to the lowest common available version.

Comment: I can but REST clients only available after TFS2015, so for the versions older than TFS 2015, I have to use SOAP libraries. That's why I want to find out TFS version so that I can perform SOAP and REST api calls after checking specific TFS version.

Comment: Then try to call a REST API that's available in every version of TFS after 2015. If you get a 404 error or an exception (or similar), catch the exception and assume it's a version that requires the SOAP libraries.

Answer (score -1):

No, we cannot get the semantic version number from TFS collection URI only.

From TFS 2010 onwards, we can check the Product Version (semantic version number) from **Application Tier** Summary on TFS Administration Console. See [Open the Administration Console for Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/open-admin-console?view=azure-devops-2022) for details.

[image]

We can also check what platform we use by opening the **About** page (`https://ServerName/CollectionName/_home/About`) for TFS (Azure DevOps Server). See [Look up your Azure DevOps platform and version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/lookup-platform-version?view=azure-devops)

[image]